# Usage of Anymore/Any more

Tags: adverbs, determiners

Do these sentences use 'anymore/any more' correctly?

1. We won't be trying **any more** of those products.
2. We won't be trying those products **anymore**.
3. Spotlight's on him now, he won't be trying **anymore** funny business; for a while anyway.

Note: I made up Sentence 1 & 2. Sentence 3,  which I don't feel certain about, was found on Google Books.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any more (two words) can be used as:

(A) an adverb about quantities or numbers - is there any more beer? Have you seen any more birds? Used like this, it means roughly the same as 'some more'.

(B) also an adverb, meaning 'no longer' or 'in the past but not now'. In this meaning, we use it in the end position - I don't drink tea any more, bus tickets are not cheap any more, I won't be seeing Mary any more.

'Anymore' (one word) is a mainly US English variation for meaning (B).

In your sentences, (1) is correct (meaning A), 2 is correct (meaning B) and (3) is incorrect (should be 'any more funny business' - meaning A).

[Any more or anymore?](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/any-more-or-anymore)

Comment: Or, it could have been "Spotlight's on him now, he won't be trying funny business anymore; for a while anyway." Isn't it also a correct way?

Comment: Yes, you can rewrite the sentence that way.

Comment: @Mathew That sounds odd to me, though I can't explain why. I would say *"he won't be trying **any** funny business anymore"*.